# xUnit testing method that utilises UI

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm

I am new to C#. I have been trying to write a xUnit Test for the method below ("ExecuteExportCsvCommand()"). However, it has some UI control as you can see below.
Therefore, I don't know how to test the function. If anyone can explain, I would be really thankful.

```
 public void ExecuteExportCsvCommand()
    {
        ExecuteCancelPopOutWindowCommand();
        var previousState = View.IsEnabled;
        View.IsEnabled = false;
        try
        {
            var exportDialog = new ExportPrintDataDialog();
            var result = exportDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                var projectData = _projectService.GetProject3dObject(Project.Id);

                IEnumerable<object> orderedList;
                orderedList = projectData.Select((x, i) => new ExportData {
                    Index = i,
                    Time = x.Time,
                    LayerNumber = x.LayerNumber,
                    X = x.X,
                    Y = x.Y,
                    Z = x.Z,
                    ArcVoltage = x.ArcVoltage,
                    Current = x.Current,
                    WireFeedSpeed = x.WireFeedSpeed,
                    WireFeedSpeedB = x.WireFeedSpeedB,
                    RatioWireFeedSpeed = (x.WireFeedSpeed == 0) ? 0 : x.WireFeedSpeedB / x.WireFeedSpeed,
                    BuildHeight = x.WallHeight,
                    LeadTemperature = x.LeadTemperature,
                    TrailTemperature = x.TrailTemperature,
                    OxygenLevel = x.OxygenLevel,
                    GasFlowA = x.GasFlow.First(),
                    GasFlowB = x.GasFlow.Last(),
                    TempChannels = x.TempChannels //preferably last as array of 8 values
                }).ToList();

                //Define Column headers
                var heightHeader = _options.CorriOptions.Value.UseWallHeight ? "Wall Height" : "Layer Height";
                var wfsHeader = Project.ProcessEnum == EnumProjectProcess.CW_MIG 
                    ? new []{ "Hot Wire Feed Speed", "Cold Wire Feed Speed" } 
                    : new[] { "Wire Feed Speed 1", "Wire Feed Speed 2" };
                var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "Index" , "Ordinal Number" },
                    { "Time" , "Time" },
                    { "LayerNumber" , "Layer Number" },
                    { "X" , "Pos X" },
                    { "Y" , "Pos Y" },
                    { "Z" , "Pos Z" },
                    { "ArcVoltage" , "Arc Voltage" },
                    { "Current" , "Current" },
                    { "WireFeedSpeed" , wfsHeader.First() },
                    { "WireFeedSpeedB" , wfsHeader.Last()  },
                    {"RatioWireFeedSpeed", "R-Ratio"},
                    { "BuildHeight" , heightHeader },
                    { "LeadTemperature" , "Lead Temperature" },
                    { "TrailTemperature" , "Trail Temperature" },
                    { "OxygenLevel" , "Oxygen Level" },
                    { "GasFlowA" , "GasFlow Channel A" },
                    { "GasFlowB" , "GasFlow Channel B" },
                    { "TempChannels" , "End Effector Temperature (Channels 1 - 8)" }
                };

                var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
                {
                    Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*",
                    FilterIndex = 1,
                    RestoreDirectory = true,
                    FileName = string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHHmm"), "_log"),
                };

                if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
                {
                    using var writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName);
                    using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(new ExportDataMapper(headers));
                    csv.WriteRecords(orderedList);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            View.IsEnabled = previousState;
            ExportDataBtnChecked = false;
        }
    }
```

The test environment was set up already as you can see below. I just have to write the test for the method mentioned. If you need further details, please let me know. thanks.

```
public class ProjectPrintViewModelTests
{
    private readonly ProjectPrintViewModel _sut;
    private readonly IHost _host;

    private readonly Mock<IPermissionChecker> _permissionChecker = new Mock<IPermissionChecker>();
    private readonly Mock<ILogService> _logService = new Mock<ILogService>();
    private readonly Mock<IAuditService> _auditService = new Mock<IAuditService>();
    private readonly Mock<IProjectService> _projectService = new Mock<IProjectService>();

    public ProjectPrintViewModelTests()
    {
        var colorList = new List<string> {
            "DefaultMinColor",
            "DefaultLowColor",
            "DefaultNormColor",
            "DefaultHighColor",
            "DefaultMaxColor"
        };

        var app = new Application();
        colorList.ForEach(x => app.Resources.Add(x, Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255)));

        _host = MockEnvironment.BuildHost();
        IoCContainer.SetServiceProvider(_host.Services);
        
        var options = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<OptionsContainer>();
        var valueService = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<IValuePointService>();
        var project = new ProjectViewModel(options);
        
        _sut = new ProjectPrintViewModel(
            options,
            project,
            _logService.Object,
            _permissionChecker.Object,
            _auditService.Object,
            _projectService.Object,
            valueService,
            false);
    }

    /// Write Tests Below Here

    [Fact]
    public void ExecuteCsvFileCommand_WhenValueAreValid()
    {
        //Assemble

        //Act
        _sut.ExecuteExportCsvCommand();

        //Assert
```

Comment: Is this part of an exercise you have to complete or is this part of an existing project you're working on? In either case, you will need to extract the UI code and use an abstraction to hide the implementation of the UI parts from the unit test, because you cannot unit test UI code like that. Just like the other services, you will need to create an interface, inject it in your class and then use a Mock for it in your test scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, This is part of an existing project. any similar example code you can help with please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the many disadvantages of having poor design and non-clean architecture.. Separating UI code from business logic helps you in testing your business logic well.

Keep in mind that unit tests should run/return as fast as possible. Apparently, showing a SaveFileDialog will stop the test until a user selects the path, this is wrong!

You should pull all UI-related code out to a separate component that delivers UI services, For example:

```
public interface IUiServices
{
    void CancelPopOutWindow();
    void SaveViewState();
    void RestoreViewState();
    bool ShowExportDialog();
    string ShowSaveFileDialog();
}
```

The most important part is, when testing, you'd mock the UIServices to not do any real UI work (Ex. opinging SaveFileDialog, it will just return a valid test path to save files in there).. So `ExecuteExportCsvCommand` can be look like this..

```
public void ExecuteExportCsvCommand()
{
    _uiServices.CancelPopOutWindow();
    _uiServices.SaveViewState();
    try
    {
        var b = _uiServices.ShowExportDialog();
        
        if (b)
        {
            var projectData = _projectService.GetProject3dObject(Project.Id);

            IEnumerable<object> orderedList;
            orderedList = projectData.Select((x, i) => new ExportData {
                Index = i,
                Time = x.Time,
                LayerNumber = x.LayerNumber,
                X = x.X,
                Y = x.Y,
                Z = x.Z,
                ArcVoltage = x.ArcVoltage,
                Current = x.Current,
                WireFeedSpeed = x.WireFeedSpeed,
                WireFeedSpeedB = x.WireFeedSpeedB,
                RatioWireFeedSpeed = (x.WireFeedSpeed == 0) ? 0 : x.WireFeedSpeedB / x.WireFeedSpeed,
                BuildHeight = x.WallHeight,
                LeadTemperature = x.LeadTemperature,
                TrailTemperature = x.TrailTemperature,
                OxygenLevel = x.OxygenLevel,
                GasFlowA = x.GasFlow.First(),
                GasFlowB = x.GasFlow.Last(),
                TempChannels = x.TempChannels //preferably last as array of 8 values
            }).ToList();

            //Define Column headers
            var heightHeader = _options.CorriOptions.Value.UseWallHeight ? "Wall Height" : "Layer Height";
            var wfsHeader = Project.ProcessEnum == EnumProjectProcess.CW_MIG 
                ? new []{ "Hot Wire Feed Speed", "Cold Wire Feed Speed" } 
                : new[] { "Wire Feed Speed 1", "Wire Feed Speed 2" };
            var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "Index" , "Ordinal Number" },
                { "Time" , "Time" },
                { "LayerNumber" , "Layer Number" },
                { "X" , "Pos X" },
                { "Y" , "Pos Y" },
                { "Z" , "Pos Z" },
                { "ArcVoltage" , "Arc Voltage" },
                { "Current" , "Current" },
                { "WireFeedSpeed" , wfsHeader.First() },
                { "WireFeedSpeedB" , wfsHeader.Last()  },
                {"RatioWireFeedSpeed", "R-Ratio"},
                { "BuildHeight" , heightHeader },
                { "LeadTemperature" , "Lead Temperature" },
                { "TrailTemperature" , "Trail Temperature" },
                { "OxygenLevel" , "Oxygen Level" },
                { "GasFlowA" , "GasFlow Channel A" },
                { "GasFlowB" , "GasFlow Channel B" },
                { "TempChannels" , "End Effector Temperature (Channels 1 - 8)" }
            };

            string path = _uiServices.ShowSaveFileDialog();
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            {
                using var writer = new StreamWriter(path);
                using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(new ExportDataMapper(headers));
                csv.WriteRecords(orderedList);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _uiServices.RestoreViewState();
        ExportDataBtnChecked = false;
    }
}
```